# echo "You have not entered a file"

Tags: unix, if-statement, for-loop, echo

The problem is that I want to echo a string "You have not entered a file".

Simply put, if the user literally inputs nothing after calling a Unix script, they will receive that error message.

Here is my code

```
for var in "$@"
do

file=$var

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "You have not entered a file"
elif [ -d $file ]
then
   echo "Your file is a directory"
elif [ -e $file ]
then
   sendToBin
else
  echo "Your file $file does not exist"
fi
done
```

I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong, I believe it's something in my first if statement

Answer (score 3):

If the user enters no arguments, then `$@` will be empty -- in other words, your loop runs 0 times. That check needs to happen outside the loop.

Additionally, with your `-d` and `-e` checks, you should quote `"$file"`, otherwise if the user entered an empty string as an arg, you will get unexpected behavior (it would be as if no arg had been passed, and in that case `-d` and `-e` actually will end up returning *true*).

Answer (score 1):

As [FatalError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172428/fatalerror) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074374/15168), the problem is that you never enter the `for` loop when there are no arguments.

You therefore need something more like:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then echo "You have not entered a file"
else
    for file in "$@"
    do
        if [ -d "$file" ]
        then echo "$file is a directory"
        elif [ -e "$file" ]
        then sendToBin # Does this need $file as an argument?  Why not?
        else echo "File $file does not exist"
        fi
    done
fi
```

You can decide whether error messages should be prefixed with the script name (`$(basename $0 .sh)` is what I usually use), and whether they should be sent to standard error (`>&2`).