# Trying to return a simple echo statement

Tags: unix, if-statement, echo

I want to output "You have not entered a file".

If the user literally inputs nothing after calling a Unix script, they will receive that error message.

```
for var in "$@"
do

file=$var

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "You have not entered a file"
elif [ -d $file ]
then
   echo "Your file is a directory"
elif [ -e $file ]
then
   sendToBin
else
  echo "Your file $file does not exist"
fi
```

I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong, I believe it's something in my first if statement

Comment: What error exactly? Also, you should quote arguments to `[` (as in `[ -d "$file" ]`), or use `[[`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [echo "You have not entered a file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074107/echo-you-have-not-entered-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite that like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "You have not entered a file"
else
    for file in "$@"; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            echo "Your file is a directory"
        elif [ -e "$file" ]; then
            echo sendToBin "$file"
        else
            echo "Your file $file does not exist"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Important points:

- The structure of your script should be to first check if any arguments were passed. If there aren’t any, print an appropriate message. Otherwise handle each argument. So do an `if ... else for ...`.
- For arithmetic, I use [arithmetic evaluation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic). The manual is confusing about where all this can be be used, but you can do `if (( ... ))` and also C-style `for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ ))`.
- Always wrap any variables like `$file` in quotes: `"$file"`. If there is something as simple as a space in a filename, it will break otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The check on `$#` is run only within a `for` that loops over the positional parameters - that is, due to the loop, the `[ $# -gt 0 ]` will only be run if `$#` is non-zero. Try moving the check outside the loop.

(Also, most of your `$file`s should be quoted (`"$file"`).)